# How can I fit my initial loaded page to the width of display when using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had wide length table with using twitter-bootstrap.css.
The content was sticking out from the edge of the table so I added this line to bootstrap.css.

> min-width: 400px;

**bootstrap.css**

```
body { 
    min-width: 400px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background-color: #27292b;
    background: url('/assets/body-bg.jpg');
}
```

But now, When my smart-phone loads the page, initial looks zoomed up as default.
How can I make it fit?

**index.html**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bootstrap, it is not straightforward to show tables with large amounts of content, especially on mobile devices.

First think about how much content is needed on a mobile device, and if still a problem, you can increase the size of the mobile viewport by reducing the initial-scale in the viewport meta tag as so:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">`

This would double how much you could see - adjust the `initial-scale` value as appropriate.

Have a look at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive if you want to find out how to hide some of your `<td>` elements on mobile devices.